# Desktop notifications should use the icon of the site they originated from

Tags: feature-request, chat, google-chrome

For example, while looking at a beta site in chat, and receiving a notification from someone on a [Super User](http://superuser.com) chat room, the icon in the notification will have the default Stack Exchange icon:

[image]

It would be great if it had the icon of the site to which the chat room (from which the message originated) belongs.

Alternatively, it would also be perfectly fine to see the users avatar. Just like when you have the specific chat room active:

[image]

Comment: This definitely needs to be revisited.

Answer (score 1):

This would be only helpful when you chatting on more than one SE network. But if you are using only SU or SO chat room then obviously you already know that from which network you have got the reply. Also there is different alert ring for desktop notification, as I have personal experience of SO and SU and both use different alert ring for the desktop notification.

But although it would be nice to see that feature on Desktop notification because it will help a lot those users who join more than one chat room at the same time.

Comment: I have edited my post, may be it will help you now :)