# Chat notification uses the wrong icon

Tags: bug, chat, desktop-notifications

With the desktop notifications enabled (Chrome, OSX 10.7.5), I'm getting the wrong site icons on the notifications. Not every time, but often. Note that in the below screenshot, the icon is from SciFi, but the notification is not. I'm in both rooms, of course, but the icon should match the originating room.

[image: Ping with wrong icon]

Comment: It uses the last room you opened a chat window to. This is by-design to keep traffic low.

Comment: If it's going to show the wrong icon so often, why bother having a site icon at all? Maybe it should just show the network icon if you have 2+ open.

Comment: It doesn't know how many you have open when it loads, that may be the cause. However, I would suggest not sweating the small stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Desktop notifications should use the icon of the site they originated from](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144099/desktop-notifications-should-use-the-icon-of-the-site-they-originated-from)